# Change HTML text by URL using *.ini config file

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, ini

I am trying to find out a good way to change HTML text by the URL currently displayed. I've got a list of all addresses what could appear in the URL line and corresponding text stored in *.ini file.

**HTML**

```
...
<?php $conf = parse_ini_file('config.ini.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   var baseurl = window.location.href
   $("ul.navbar li a").each(function(){
     if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == baseurl )
     $(this).parent('li').addClass("active");
   })
 });
</script>
...
<h4 class="panel-title">Home</h4>
...
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['webaddr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_0']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_1_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_1']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_2_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_2']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_3_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_3']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_4_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_4']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_5_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_5']; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $conf['page_6_addr']; ?>"><?php echo $conf['page_6']; ?></a></li>
</ul>
...
```

***.INI**

```
...
[site_url]
webaddr='http://example.com/';  -- be sure to include forward slash after the web address!

[pages]
page_0='Home';
page_1='Page 1';
page_2='Page 2';
page_3='Page 3';
page_4='Page 4';
page_5='Page 6';
page_6='Page 7';

[pages_addr]
page_0_addr='#';
page_1_addr='page1.php';
page_2_addr='page2.php';
page_3_addr='page3.php';
page_4_addr='page4.php';
page_5_addr='page5.php';
page_6_addr='page6.php';
...
```

The text to change in this case would be **Home** in **H4 element**

I though the best solution will be using JavaScript, but I don't know how to correctly parse the *.ini file into JavaSrcipt and how to compare then.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I'm assuming the `parse_ini_file` php function worked for you. So you can turn this into a javascript question by copy/pasting the HTML that was emitted (click View Source on the web page).

Comment: I just need some way to change that text in h4. I though the javascript will be the best for this case, but I am not really good in JavaScript and basicly don't know how the function should look like. It could be in PHP, but I've got a feeling like it would be way too many extra lines of extra code, when JavaScript can handle this better.

Comment: Plus since I've got URL reading as JavaScript, I though I can use that existing script, only add few lines of extra code, instead of creating the same function for reading URL yet again in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$("h4").text($li.text());` to set the text of the `<h4>` to the text of the active `<li>`.

Below, the iframe is running as stacksnippets.com/js so the `js` page is highlighted.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.active {
  background: #dfd;
  border: 1px solid #efe;
}

a {
 color: gray;
 padding: 10px;
}

a:visited {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".navbar li a").each(function() {
      var $anchor = $(this);
      var $li = $anchor.parent('li');
      if ($anchor.attr("href") === pgurl) {
        $li.addClass("active");
        $("h4").text($li.text());
      }
    })
  });
</script>

<h4 class="panel-title">Home</h4>

<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="js">JavaScript</a></li>
  <li><a href="another">Another</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added some CSS so you can see which one is active.

Comment: Didn't think about it this way, but it works exactly as I've intended to use it! Thx a lot life-saver ;)